# $2^n=7x^2+y^2$ solutions

Tags: proof-explanation

My problem is related to the equation from above. It actually is a very particular one. I noticed that for every positive integer $n$ there's ONE SINGLE solution $(x_1,y_1)$ so that $x_1$ and $y_1$ are ODD positive integers ( I didn't prove it, I tested it with a program through roughly 30 tests).
If that's true , then how can I prove it? I tried to make a proof by absurd reduction ( assuming the contrary of sentence , that is , there could be at least one more solution for some values of n but not necessarly any n and run into a contradiction) which didn't work, and personally I can't "feel" why it can't be more than one solution. I hope you could help me to prove it. Thanks in advance!
P.s.: $n>=3$ .

Comment: How do you solve $2=7x^2+y^2$ ?  Here, $n=1$,. certainly a positive integer.  For larger exponents, you can build a solution by starting with a solution for $n=2,3$ and multiplying by $2^{2k}$ for appropriate $k$.

Comment: Ah, I missed the condition that $x,y$ be odd.  My trick doesn't work with that rule.

Comment: @lulu OP is restricting allowed solutions to **odd** positive integers, so the solutions obtained by multiplying by $2^{2k}$ are irrelevant.  Also, this pattern has to start at $n=3$ since there is no solution to $4=7x^2+y^2$ either.

Comment: @MarkFischler  Yeah, I missed the "odd" condition (pointed that out in my second comment).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solutions of $x^2 + 7y^2 = 2^n$ where $x$ and $y$ are odd numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483872/solutions-of-x2-7y2-2n-where-x-and-y-are-odd-numbers)

Comment: @lulu the equation is the same but my question is NOT about the way I can prove that for any integer n>=3 there is a solution of the equation, (x,y), with x and y odd and positive integers, it's about the way I can prove that there's EXACTLY one solution for any integer n>=3. (don't know how to use bold)

Comment: Understood.  I'll retract the close vote accordingly, but I'll leave up the duplicate citation, as I expect that the solutions provided there will provide guidance toward a proof of uniqueness.

Comment: Indeed, the first posted solution to the earlier question includes a proof of uniqueness (Note:  I did not check that argument carefully, but it looked sensible on a quick read).

Answer (score 0):

2^n    ≡ y^2 mod 7  ⇒ y^2 < 7

It can be seen that y^2 can only have values 1, 2 and 4. Only 1 and 4 are acceptable if y is integer, that is y= (+ or -) 1 or y =(+ or -) 2. With these values of y some powers of n give integers for x, for example y=2, x =6 for n=8 or x=y=2 for n=5. 
This is the reason for existing only one single x and y for every n.

Comment: why the value 2 is not acceptable? Actually, 2 mod 7.

Comment: Anonymus, because 2^0.5 is not integer.

Comment: Wrong answer. $2^n\equiv y^2\pmod{7}$ does not imply that $y^2<7$.

Comment: User236182 Can you correct me and give the right answer? thanks in advance.

Comment: user23618. Of course y^2 can be greater than 7. I have assumed (regarding the equation) that y^2<7 to prove that for any value of y there are only single values for n and x, this is what the question is about!